# How to present Spotify Playlist data?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, get, fetch, jsx

I am trying to pull user's Spotify playlist information from Spotify and present it on the app I am creating.

Here are the steps I've taken, can someone help me to see where the mistake is?

1) Add a method into Spotify.js

```
  const Spotify = {
    bringPlaylist() {
      return fetch(`https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/playlists`)
        .then(
          response => {
            if (response.ok) {
              return response.json();
            }
            throw new Error("Request failed!");
          },
          networkError => {
            console.log(networkError.message);
          }
        )
        .then(jsonResponse => {
          return jsonResponse;
        });
    }
  };
```

2) Import Spotify.js into App.js, create a method in App.js to call bringSpotifylist, set the state, and bind it.

```
import Spotify from "../../util/Spotify.js";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      spotifyList: []
    };

    this.bringPlaylist = this.bringPlaylist.bind(this);
  }

  bringPlaylist() {
    Spotify.bringPlaylist().then(spotifyList => {
      this.setState({ spotifyList: spotifyList });
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <SpotifyPlaylist spotifyList={this.state.spotifyList} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

- Here is the spotify API information I referred to : https://developer.spotify.com/console/get-playlists/?user_id=wizzler

Comment: What do you expect to happen when the component is mounted? Do you expect the state to contain the song list or an empty array?

Comment: @Gh05d I expect the state the contain list of playlists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you created the function to fetch the data, but it is never called. You would have to move it to a lifecycle method like `componentDidMount`, make it async and call it:

```
  componentDidMount() { // App.js
    Spotify.bringPlaylist().then(spotifyList => {
      this.setState({ spotifyList: spotifyList });
    });
  }
```

You would also need logic for *loading* and *error* states. Read more about it [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-ajax.html) in the docs.

**EDIT**

Here is a full example for a better explanation:

```
import Spotify from "../../util/Spotify.js";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      spotifyList: [],
      loading: true,
      error: null
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    Spotify.bringPlaylist().then(
      spotifyList => {
        this.setState({ spotifyList, loading: false });
      },
      error => {
        this.setState({
          loading: false,
          error
        });
      }
    );
  }

  render() {
    const { error, loading, spotifyList } = this.state;
    if (error) {
      return <div>Error: {error.message}</div>;
    } else if (loading) {
      return <div>Loading...</div>;
    } else {
      return (
        <div>
          <SpotifyPlaylist spotifyList={this.state.spotifyList} />
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
}
```

There are two new state properties: `error` and `loading`. Depending on which one has a *truthy* value, different *html* will be displayed. When the component mounts, `loading` will be true, as the data will be fetched from the API. It either results in an error or in a successful fetch, so depending on which, the error html or the `<Spotify/>` Component will be displayed.

Comment: I've updated my code as you suggested and also changed `this.bringPlaylist = this.bringPlaylist.bind(this) ` to `this.componentDidMount = this.componentDidMount.bind(this);` However, reading through the document you attached, still not clear what I am doing wrong when adding the error states (above in `const Spotify` after fetch).

Comment: What? No, you don't have to bind `componentDidMount`. It is a lifecycle method and binded by default. Basically, functions called in there will fire after the component has mounted and only then. That is why it is a perfect place for data fetching. I will update my answer for a full example, so that it gets clearer.